# What are the best resources you've seen for learning WCF? (books, sites, etc.)

Tags: wcf, web-services

Just wondering what are the most useful resources you've seen for learning about WCF?

I've created a few prototypes and understand the basics, however I'm starting a fairly high-profile project and would like to fill in as many gaps in my knowledge as possible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Books:**

[Learning WCF: A Hands-on Guide by Michele Bustamante](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101627) - very nice kick-off book with step-by-step tutorials. Michelle also has a [series of webcasts published on MSDN](http://www.dasblonde.net/2007/06/24/WCFWebcastSeries.aspx).

[Programming WCF Services by Juval Lowy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521308) - more systematic approach, for experienced web developers.

[IDesign WCF Coding Standard](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/download/IDesign%20WCF%20Coding%20Standard.zip)

[WCF Security Guidance from Microsoft P&P](http://www.codeplex.com/WCFSecurity)

**Websites:**

[Getting Started Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx) on MSDN

and offcourse [TheBestProgrammersQandASiteEver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcf) :-)

Comment: hello 
do you know where i could buy a pdf version of this book ?

Answer (score 6):

From the three books i started reading after other devs' recomendations i liked:

[Windows® Communication Foundation 4 Step by Step](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145302403.do)

The best about this book is that it helps you understand with a very simple and effective way and it has a lot of examples and all needed instructions to get you started fast..

Answer (score 3):

I've always told people safari bookshelf is a great site.  Saves you the money of buying books initially and you can scan what you're looking for.

Nothing worse than buying a $50 book that gets used twice and sits on your book shelf next to some CGI coding book, .NET 1.0 , and some old Oracle book

Answer (score 3):

The [WCF Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf/).

Answer (score 2):

I *really* liked [Inside Windows Communication Foundation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623066).  It tells you a few things that most other books don't:

1. What the design goals of WCF are
2. Different messaging and coordination patterns and what support WCF has for them
3. The organization of WCF (Relationship between bindings, channels, etc).  A few other books have this, but I found this book to have the most hands-on explanation of them - which I like.

Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [Nicholas Allen's Indigo blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/drnick/).

Answer (score 1):

From SO i found:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805902/where-can-i-find-good-resources-on-wcf

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386801/wcf-book-recommendation